# AVAudioUnitSampler not deallocating resource

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory, sprite-kit, avaudioengine

I have created an `AVAudioUnitSampler`, but after inspecting memory via the `Instruments` tool, it appears that when the scene is changed, even though the `AVAudioUnitSampler` object is nil, the resources it initially loaded the first time around are still in memory. When I recreate the sampler, it reloads the resource and now I have double the amount of memory used for the sampler. How can I force the resources to deallocate?

Here's the code:

```
-(void) loadSampler {
    // Instatiate audio engine
    _engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
    _mixer = [_engine mainMixerNode];
    _sampler = [[AVAudioUnitSampler alloc] init];

    [self loadSoundFontInstrument]; //sound font is the instrument that the sampler will use to play sounds

    [self makeEngineConnections];
    [self startEngine];
}

-(void) loadSoundFontInstrument {
    if (_sampler != nil) {
        NSString* instrument = [[GameData sharedGameData].settings valueForKey:@"instrument"]; //decides on what sound font file to use
        NSURL *piano = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:instrument ofType:@"sf2"]];
        [_sampler loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL:piano program:0 bankMSB:0x79 bankLSB:0 error:nil];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Sampler has not been initialized");
}

-(void)makeEngineConnections {
    [_engine attachNode:_sampler];
    [_engine connect:_sampler to:_mixer format:[_sampler outputFormatForBus:0]];
}

-(void)startEngine {
    [_engine startAndReturnError:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue, but I'm not entirely sure why my solution solved it. Upon looking at the `Leaks` instrument, I noticed that the retain count for the `_sampler` variable was 2. The class (that you cannot see called `MIDIController` owns the `_sampler` object. The `_engine` object also retains a reference to the sampler. Even when I make my midi controller object nil, the sampler still remains in memory with a retain count of 1. The weird thing is that there is no longer any reference to the `_engine` object since it's parent has been deallocated so I'm not sure why it still persists.

TLDR: In short, I made `_sampler`, `_engine` and `_mixer` nil and that solved it.